# Having Trouble Making Windows 10 Bootable Usb

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I recently reset my laptop which was dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu. So I reinstalled Ubuntu  and planned to make a bootable USB of windows 10 in it so I log on and install the windows 10 iso and unetbootin I flashed the iso and restarted my computer with the USB in nothing happened. I then went into my bios and forced it to boot from USB and the screen went blank until I turned the computer off. I then tried balenaEtcher which told me to use woeusb(which wouldn't install gave me the error woeusb : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg)). Then I tried to use startup disk creator(which also didn't work it didn't let me put files in), and RosaImageWriter which had the same result. There where probably a couple others. Any help would be appreciated I am running the latest version of Ubuntu on a hp elitebook folio 9480m. Thank you!

Comment: So you want to make a windows 10 installation media?

Comment: Does these answer your question? https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/              https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu

Comment: Yes @SasukeUchiha I want to make a windows 10 installation media and the first article does works but the exact same thing happens and woeusb gave me the error woeusb : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable.

Comment: Can't you get your hands on a windows machine? It's much easier that way. Just did a quick google search and there are a lot of articles referring to that error. https://www.google.com/search?q=error+woeusb+%3A+Depends%3A+libwxgtk3.0-0v5+(%3E%3D+3.0.4%2Bdfsg)&oq=error+woeusb+%3A+Depends%3A+libwxgtk3.0-0v5+(%3E%3D+3.0.4%2Bdfsg)&aqs=chrome..69i57.785j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I have read through all of them and none of them solved my problem and I'm working on trying to get it flashed on a windows machine but I'm starting to think that its my bios.

Comment: If so you should be able to update BIOS.